# Uploading multiple files using pythons requests Library loop through a folder in your computer pyhton suggestons

Tags: python, api, loops, multipartform-data

I am aware you are can upload multiple files to post in an api using this,

ex.

```
test_files = {
    "test_file_1": open("my_file.txt", "rb"),
    "test_file_2": open("my_file_2.txt", "rb"),
    "test_file_3": open("my_file_3.txt", "rb")
}
```

but i want to change the files often so the solution i thought of is to drop all the files in a folder and loop through the folder to upload each file.

the part i am stuck on is how can i loop though the folder

```
path = "/Users/mycode/Documents/API_upload/"

files = {
    'file': open(p,'rb') for p in os.listdir(path)
}
```

I tried this but doesnt work as the files need to be in the directory for it to work.
any other suggestions for this.

thanks.

Comment: "files need to be in the directory for it to work" then where are those files?

Comment: sorry i should have added the directory. its with in path. i just edited it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add base path to the file name

```
path = "/Users/mycode/Documents/API_upload/"

files = {f'file_{i}': open(f'{path}/{name}','rb') for i, name in enumerate(os.listdir(path))}
```

Comment: thanks! I used files = {f'file': open(f'{path}/{name}','rb') for i, name in enumerate(os.listdir(path))} and it works!! I have been stuck on this for a while but that made my code work!